# Could not load Interop.WIA error with asp.net C# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page using ASP.Net C# 4.0, that will be used to detect scanner deployed with a server and save scanned images to the server. I have created this page using WIA (Windows Image Acquisition). This page is working and scanning images when I run it within asp.net development server, but when I deploy it in IIS 6.0 it says:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WIA' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.*

Is it because of WIA being a COM component ? Or is there anything which I am missing when deployed in IIS ? 
Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." Usually means you're trying to load 32-bit code into a 64-bit process or vice-versa.

Try setting your IIS app pool to 32-bit (some info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true))

Answer (score 0):

Got to Start->Run->type inetmgr and on the left application pools, select DefaultAppPool and the virtual directory name of the app and for both make sure to enable 32 -bit applications to true, am using IIS7.0 and windows 7 64-bit.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419403/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception)