# Could not load file or assembly 'EfTidyNet' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am trying to host an application on IIS 7.0, this application is using a third party dll 
EFTidynet.dll for removing unwanted html code in the application. when i am running this application using Visual Studio 2010, its working fine, but when i hosted this application on IIS 7.0 its giving the error of
Could not load file or assembly 'EfTidyNet' or one of its dependencies.

I have already added the name in the assemblies section on web.config but still no success.

Can anybody help me out.

Comment: Have you put EfTidyNet and all its dependencies on the server?

Comment: Yes i have put all the dependency

Answer (score 0):

EfTidyNet (on codeproject.com) seems to contain only one DLL.  The directions say that it needs to be registered in the GAC.

I usually create a folder in my c:\inetpub\ folder named "Bin" or "DLL" or "GAC".  It makes it much easier to find registered files (that I'm using for IIS).  Microsoft has plenty of good instructions on GACing a file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: helo tgolisch I got zero success.

Comment: I would like to help you but you really haven't given me much information.  I don't know what you have done or what symptoms you are seeing.  Has anything changed?  How do you know?  Have you tried anything to isolate the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to register the assembly in GAC but I was not able to register it in GAC, because it requires the Strong name for assembly. I tried to Sign the Assembly but its not being sign. I have tried many tools for the same. In my Scenario I have hosted my application in IIS7.0. and I have used the Eftidynet for cleaning up the bad html. when I tried to access the site by iis its gives me error of EFtidynet dll could not be load and not able to load its dependency.

Comment: It sounds like you have isolated your problem: you cannot GAC the assembly because it is not signed.  Maybe you could search S/O for instructions about signing an assembly.  Keep trying until you succeed.  Then you can GAC your dll and it will all work.

Answer (score 0):

On my development machine, I was having the same error message, followed by:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Apparently, EfTidyNet is a 32-bit DLL, which didn't work too well on my 64-bit version of Windows 8.

The error disappeared after I **enabled 32-bit applications** in the advanced settings of the application pool of the web site, as explained here:
[Could not load file or assembly exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419403/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception#9419522)