# Visual Studio C# SSIS: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a new SSIS project in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. Unfortunately, it is returning the following;

[image]

> ===================================
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft
>   Visual Studio)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.DeserializeManifestInProjectMode(XmlNode
>   manifestNode)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.ConstructProjectHierarchyFrom(ProjectSerialization
>   projectSerialization)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.Deserialize(TextReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.Serialization.BaseProjectLoader.Load(IFileProjectHierarchy
>   projectHierarchy)    at
>   Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.FileProjectHierarchy.Load(String
>   pszFilename, UInt32 grfMode, Int32 iReadOnly)

This has worked previously and I am not sure what has changed to cause it throw these errors. Having searched Stack I have seen that there are several similar questions to this however, as far as I have seen, none regarding this specific issue. I have tried activating 64 bit version as per suggestion by [Mike Gledhill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061306/4162689). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As of a month or so ago, the SSIS packages I was working on were not supported in '17 at all yet. I always had to roll back to '15 to work with SSIS. But, maybe that's changed...

Comment: Thanks Collin, I will reassess :/

Comment: I'm getting the same error (with a different version) on VS2017 while trying to work on an existing SSRS project. VERY FRUSTRATING.